# disable remote site project debugging vs 2008

Tags: asp.net, wcf, debugging, remote-debugging

i have a remote web site project in my sln that contains a wcf service and the server does not allow me to debug him... 
when i run my client i get an error on the start that the server cannot be debugged..
how can i tell the vs to stop trying to debug the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both a client and a server project in the same solution, then VS2008 is capable of debugging either one or both at the same time. There are two independent settings that control this.

1. Right-click on the solution and select "Set Startup Projects". This allows you to select any number of projects to start in the debugger when you press F5. Any project not in the startup list may very well be run anyway if it's a server, but *will not be run in the VS2008 debugger* - an important distinction.
2. Every ASMX and WCF service project has a property in its property window called "Always Start When Debugging" that controls whether VS2008 will auto-start it in the debugger when the client project is run.

I therefore suggest that you:

1. make sure that the server project is *not* set as one of the solution startup projects, and
2. make sure that the server project is *not* set to always start when debugging.

Comment: i'm sure this is useful information but i'v already split the project to 2 solutions...